# Modifying array with asycronus data

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a very curious problem that I'm sure someone in the world has figure out. Let's keep thing simple however. Ok, here we go.

So I have a plain array of objects. Let's say 5 objects for now.

```
[{id: 1, data: 'stuff'}, {id: 2, data: 'stuff'}, {id: 3, data: 'stuff'}, {id: 4, data: 'stuff'}, {id: 5, data: 'stuff'}]
```

What I then do is make 3 ajax requests which all, obviously, come back and different times. What I want to do is update this array based on the id's. For example I send off 3 ajax requests and receive new data for objects 1, 2 and 4. I'll need to update the data property in the respectives objects in the array. I'm using Array.splice to do the update. What I'm finding is that there are times, since the data comes in at different times, that things aren't updated correctly. I think this is because what splice does is actually remove the object from the array then re-inserts the new array in afterwards. It seems like there are instances when the splice method is in the middle of removing an object, then another response comes in and tries to remove another object, however, that object is not in the correct index, since the first object was removed and hasn't been inserted in yet. So the updating is off.

Comment: Do you mean "asynchronous"?

Comment: You don't want mutation, really. What you can try is using promises, with `Promise.all`, then the callback will expose the results of all requests once they're done.

Comment: @elclanrs i thought about that but i don't want to have to wait for all requests to come in. It's a vizualization app i'm working on so some requests might be quick and others might take a much longer time. i don't want users to have to wait for the longest request to finish. I want them to see the response as they come in.

Answer (score 1):

There's no reason you need to change the array at all, you are just trying to update objects within the array. Also, the index shouldn't matter because you are using the `id` property to uniquely identify each object, not the index in the array.

You should use whichever way is easiest for you to loop through the array, find the object with the corresponding `id` and update it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily handled by looping over each object and keeping a reference to the object so that you can update each object as each request completes.

```
var promiseArr = dataArr.map(function (obj) {
    return $http.get('/data/' + obj.id).then(function (result) {
        obj.data = result.data;
    });
});

// optional...
$q.all(promiseArr).then(function () {
    console.log('all done!');
});
```